# How can I add dependency on subproject programmatically in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have project with 20+ subprojects:

```
war {
    dependencies {
        runtime project(':project1')
        runtime project(':project2')
...
        runtime project(':project20')
    }
```

I would like to avoid duplication of project names here and in settings.gradle. 
How can I add dependencies on subprojects programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
war {
    dependencies {
        subprojects.each { runtime it }
    }
}
```